# Django Password reset view with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, django, api

I'm using **Django-React** in my project.
I want to use Django's `PasswordResetView` Functionality in my Django API with Reactjs as frontend.
I am using **rest_auth** for the same. I was able to send Password-reset email, but  want to change the `passwordResetConfirm` link here.

My email looks like this -

---

You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at localhost:8000.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:

http://localhost:8000/reset/MQ/60m-6b1fd2cf6df331282fe5/

Your username, in case you’ve forgotten: xxxx@xxxxx.com

Thanks for using our site!

The localhost:8000 team

---

I want it to redirect me to a link that looks like this -

http://localhost:8000/app/reset/MQ/60m-6b1fd2cf6df331282fe5/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use django-all-auth and dj-rest-auth for this functionality. I have used it in one of my project where we have frontend in reactjs and backend in django.

Comment: I've changed my question @DeepakTripathi